# Sending Documents that need to be managed by multiple departments

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to figure out the best possible way to manage a system where we will be sending out different documents via the api through one account.  These documents will need to be handled by different departments.  Is there a way in the api to share the envelope with a particular group/user?  My other idea was to create multiple department API users and depending on which document I am sending will use that departments API user and associate that API user with the department user.  It seems like a more complex solution but I know it would work.

Thanks,

Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why your question was downvoted without a reason, so I'll throw out my 2cents.

**Question 1: Is there a way in the api to share the envelope with a particular group/user?**

You can share all of a user's envelopes with group/user, but not specific envelopes. I do not suggest building a workflow around this.

**Idea 2: Create multiple department API users and depending on which document I am sending will use that departments API user and associate that API user with the department user.**

This is the best solution for scalability and customizibility, remember that an API user does not need to be an admin to create an envelope. In this case, it would be better if that user was not an admin, so they are limited to access only the envelopes that you'd want them to access.

I'm not sure what language your integration is in, but you should be able to store all of the credentials in an array/hash and just call the specific entry for username/password per workflow.

You didn't post what requirements you need for these workflows, so this is a very high level generic question and answer. You may want to go back to the drawing table and figure out your hard requirements. The solution above may not fit all of your requirements, especially if your security team has specific requirements that they need to have followed.

*example requirements*

1. Envelopes need to be created through the API
2. All envelopes must reside on the same account
3. Envelopes can't be seen by other departments
4. Envelopes need to be modified by department *DepartmentName*  after Envelope Creation
5. The API needs access to view the status of these documents